# Android how to make lateral menu like tinder

Tags: android-layout

I'm looking for examples/tutorials/framework explaining how to do a navigation bar/controller which slide to left and right like Tinder
How can i make lateral menu, like tinder with android 4.4
When i swipe with my finger, i want showing the menu on the left side.

Edit This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/zwemfest" >"



<com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="183dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.91"
    android:text="Button" />

</com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a **Navigation Drawer** http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thank's man, i try this ! You know wedoo community corporation ?